# mercurial log format with file-statuses

Tags: git, mercurial, diff, logging, show

I was wondering, how do I return files added/modified/deleted for a commit in such a format:

```
<modifier> file
<modifier> path/to/a/file
<modifier> path/to/another/file
```

In git I do this: "git show --pretty="format:" --name-status commitish" and get:

```
D       file
A       path/to/a/file
M       path/to/another/file
```

For mercurial I can't figure out how to do it with templates. I have a style file:

```
changeset = "{file_mods}{file_adds}{file_dels}"
file_add  = "A {file_add}\n"
file_mod  = "M {file_mod}\n"
file_del  = "D {file_del}\n"
```

and with this style and command "hg log -r commitish --style ~/.hgstyle" I get *almost* what I want:

```
M path/to/another/file
A path/to/a/file
D file
```

There is still one issue with mercurial - files are not sorted in good order.

How do I get the same result as on git command (with modifiers and sorted correctly) on mercurial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way using the templating engine, but you could try:

`hg log --style ~/.hgstyle -r <rev> | sort -k2`

This will sort the output of the log command on the second column of data (i.e. the file names).

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I want ;), but I'd like to do that without piping to sort if possible

Comment: actually, piping in sort does not sort alphanumerically, so I had to do the sort in ruby later in code.

Comment: Hi guys, referenced here from my question:
I assume there isn't a --template way of doing this, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
hg stat --change THE_REV_YOU_WANT
```

Comment: This still appears to sort the list by status first, so piping into `sort -k2` is still needed.

Comment: It's documented in both the built in help (`hg help status`) and on the man page http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#commands .  It's relatively new, but if it works in your version it's documented there.

Comment: I *just* noticed it in the docstring.  My local Hg source repo was updated to an older rev.

Comment: This is a good approach (I was not aware that you can pass --change to st), but it does not sort for my hg version... 1.6.3

Comment: Yeah, you have to do the sort externally -- Mercurial groups by status, but the `sort -k2` that Tim points out gets you the rest of the way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understood correctly, but if you want deletion first, then addition and finally modifications, symply change the first line of your style file :

```
changeset = "{file_dels}{file_adds}{file_mods}"
```

You can also add a tabulation (`\t`) instead of a space if you want to be closer to the Git look :

```
file_add  = "A\t{file_add}\n"
```

Comment: I don't want deletion first, I want sorted alphabetical, like in "{files}"

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.hgrc` file

```
[alias]
prettylog = log -r : --template "{rev} | {date|shortdate} | {desc|strip|firstline}\n{file_dels % '  - {file}\n'}{file_adds % '  + {file}\n'}{file_mods % '  ~ {file}\n'}\n"
```

It'll print a neatly formatted output like this (2 is the rev number):

```
2 | 2014-03-21 | my new log format
  - js/remove_me.js
  + js/add_me.js
  ~ doc/modified_me.txt
  ~ www/index.html
```